# Redirecting to facebook app registration from an Open Graph action

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I want the following flow in my application

1. User clicks on an action posted on the timeline
2. Application approval form appears
3. User approves application
4. User is redirected to a website page

Basically it is suppose to work the same way it works for socialcam.
The problem is that Open Graph actions require OG metatags in the object referenced by the action and I cant redirect it to the registration.
It seems to be a very basic flow but I couldn't find a way to do that can anyone explain how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to perform a JavaScript redirect from your Canvas URL.

In PHP, you'd echo the JavaScript like this -

```
echo "<script language=javascript>";
echo "top.location.href ='".$url."';";
echo "</script>";
exit();
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the best way to do that. I believe it can be done without redirecting

Comment: After installing an application you are redirected to the Canvas URL - that's just the way FB apps work.

Answer (score 0):

I’d say you’re looking for [Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals):

> *“Authenticated referrals is a new feature that ensures all referral traffic from Facebook to your application is already connected to Facebook. […] Once enabled, authenticated referrals causes all clicks to your app on Facebook (such as through Open Graph stories and activities published by your app) to automatically prompt a new user with the Auth dialog.”*